# Is there an ingame listing of personas that would show in a map?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

So I'm trying to get into playing multiplayer now, just 100% single player last night but I'm having a tough time getting into it.

I *know* I need to learn the maps eventually *but* getting started is tough -- especially now that the game's been out for a while now and there's a lot of more people who are familiar with most everything -- but I'm getting creamed on every map I joined because I don't know which personas appear normally in the maps.  I always chose the wrong one for the map and almost everyone chooses the right ones.  It's a lot harder for me to find my targets and everyone else can find me pretty easily.  I understand that everyone typically has to choose unique personas from everyone else but even if I had first pick, I usually pick the wrong one.

The game always shows *all* personas at the start, doesn't list or highlight what appears in the map, and you can't switch personas later within the game.  There's not even a hint of what to expect there except that tiny screenshot that *might* show some personas.  I end up leaving the game hoping I'd reconnect to the same game but never do.

**Is there some way to make the game more accessible to newer players here by showing which personas show in a map?**

Or do I just have to face it and always join a game where I stick out like a sore thumb until I learn them all myself?  Or do I have to spend a significant amount of time in the training grounds trying to figure them out myself first?  Or is it that it looks like I stick out in my perspective when really all other players see me as blended with the other personas in the map?

p.s., I would prefer not to have to go to an external website that lists the personas every time I play.

Comment: After playing a few games, it seems I have some misunderstandings about some observations I've made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I must admit I don't get the question the way it's asked at the moment. You may have misunderstood how the online games work.

What multiplayer game modes did you try? You should first try "simple" ones, like [Deathmatch](http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/Deathmatch) or the popular and well-known [Wanted](http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/Wanted).
The character you chose at the beginning is just "cosmetic" (appearance, animations, voice, etc...) and doesn't affect the gameplay. There is so no wrong choice here.
Then you chose a profile, giving abilities and perks. You will be able to change after each death and configure them when getting up in levels.

You should also play and play again the two introduction sessions to get the game mechanisms.

When trying online, some will be better than you. It will always be the case, don't worry. Just focus on what you try to do (checking the compass to get close to your target) and forget your pursuer at the beginning (anyway, when you'll be in last position, you should have no pursuer and be free to track your target without worrying too much).

The links at the beginning will explain in more detail how the game is meant to be played online.

A few key hints:

- Your target's picture is indicated on the top right of the screen. BUT there are tons of people like this on the map so, use your compass
- Compass shows your target direction and distance and relative height (above or below compared to your position)
- Lit compass means your target can see you. Start to act as stealthy as possible, not to be detected and to get more points
- Full compass means your target is very close
- When compass is full and several lookalikes are in front of you, be patient to know which one is the good one. He will sonner or later start to run, kill someone, act a weird way
- When hearing whispers, your are close to one of your pursuers, be careful, look for weird behavior, change direction to see who may be following you
- When detected, your pursuers will have a red arrow on top of them. Watch them carefully
- Use your perks carefully, they are quite long to recharge at the beginning
- Use the crowd a lot, stay close to your lookalikes to fool your pursuers
- In case of doubt, run fast :)

Please, insist, try and fail but play again, you won't regret when mastering it ;-)

Comment: I was starting out with just simple-deathmatches first just to get my feet wet. I had the impression that each map would have a certain set of personas as civilians. This was based on watching videos of other people blending with like personas everywhere. I realized that was not the case once I played a few games. It was probably all due to the game type. But I've played a fair amount of games and have gotten used to the mechanics now so I'll be able to hold my own better now.  :)

Comment: Deathmatch is a little bit different as there will be no lookalike of the personas chosen by the players (except if abilities used), which helps detection. This mode is much more fast-paced than other modes. Wanted is the real classical one. Try this one, it will be on much bigger maps and you will then perhaps live a little bit longer :)

Comment: That was exactly it, I was looking for the Wanted game type. Though Assination is more my style of play.